# How to make a headless browser mimic fully fledged browser to run an web application using selenium?

Tags: headless, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser, firefox-headless

I have a case where the need is to run a web application in a headless browser [either Google Chrome/Mozilla Firefox] but when web application is launched from the headless browser using a selenium + browser driver, our web application treats it as a unsupported browser and navigates to browser upgrade.

I know that this behavior is expected with the way our application is designed, but I need a workaround to make our application run in headless browsers by only changing the way I run headless browser with certain desired capability [if any available].

Comment: There isn't really nearly enough information here for anyone to answer, but have you tried changing the user-agent in the headless browser to a supported browser?

Comment: @frabjous: do you mean something like below?


`"--user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac
OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53"`

Comment: Yes, though the proper syntax is more likely --user-agent="...", with the quotes afterwards and no spaces around the =; not sure though, because you haven't really made clear what your exact setup is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this by adding a user-agent as a driver option

--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0

refer:

**Firefox:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox

**Google Chrome:**
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent

**Others:**
https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/